# Bootstrap remote Modal doesn't update content after first run

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

It comes javaScript and jQuery are beeing a big challenge for me. Like it's not enough I've started to use ajax to get over my problem - which is:

I've got some empty tables on my page. Each cell of a table has got its own id. A php-script is parsing a .xlsx file and puts the right link to the cell of my html table through javaScript code like:

```
document.getElementById("cellNrXY").innerHTML = "<a href=".../remoteContent.php">someLink</a>";
```

If the link is clicked, then a Modal (Bootstrap) appears and loads the remote content (which is different depending on the clicked link).

My problem was that the remote content was cached in modal, so it worked only on first run. After closing the modal and choosing another link the previous modal appeared und didn't change to the new remote content. 
I've read a lot solutions here that are based on:

```
 $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
```

but had no luck with it. After some trying with different solutions one worked properly. The only problem was: when I've clicked the second time on some other link, the modal opened up with previous content and it took some seconds for the modal beeing updated. This is why I wanted to show a rotating element while the new modal content is beeing loaded. Somewhere here I've read a solution tu use ajax for this, which I've added "on luck" and ... it worked:

```
$("#myModal").on("show.bs.modal", function(e) {
$.ajax({
beforeSend: function() { $('#myModal')
                        .html('<div class="rotatingElement"></div>')
                        .show(); },
complete: function() { $('#myModal').html.hide(); }
});
var link = $(e.relatedTarget);      
$(this).find(".modal-body").load(link.attr("href"));
});
```

The only thing is - I've no idea why this is working. Is there any chance that somebody here explain the functionality of this code to me?

Comment: do select the answer that worked for you so others having the same issue might also benefit

Answer (score 0):

if you read about the event `show.bs.modal` you will know that this event fires immediately when the show instance method is called. If caused by a click, the clicked element is available as the `relatedTarget` property of the event. Learn more about [Events](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#events)

so what is happening is every time you open a modal this event triggers and makes an [`ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) call which you see like this `$.ajax({` wchi has 2 options set

- A pre-request callback function `beforeSend`
- A function to be called when the request finishes `complete`

so whenever the modal triggeres the ajax requet is made and every time `ajax` request i made just before sending the request the modal html is overridden `$('#myModal').html('<div class="rotatingElement"></div>').show();` and a loader is added in form of a div element with class `rotatingElement` and as soon as the requet completes that loader is removed via `complete` function `$('#myModal').html.hide();` and then the `e.relatedTarget` property as described above gets the `anchor` object and the `href` of that `anchor` `.../remoteContent.php` is loaded in side the modal body in the following 2 steps

```
var link = $(e.relatedTarget);
$(this).find(".modal-body").load(link.attr("href"));
```

Comment: Hello Muhammad, thank you for the nice explanation. The ajax part is now much more clear to me.

Comment: & others: why do we need the `e.relatedTarget` property? What is it for? And why we are pushing an `e` to the function on first line?

Comment: that is the event that is passed to the function you should read about the events and the relatedTarget is the element in the DOM that triggered the event without it you wont be able to detect which element called this event function if there are multiple buttons to open the model